# Faraday Gem OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a self signed Certificate. (It is a Lab environment, consists own CA), then I managed to import the CA cert in to the Firefox. I am using this CA to sign a site `https://dev.testorg.com`

It works well with the Browser.

However same wouldn't work with the Ruby+Faraday.

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

Gem version is  `faraday (1.1.0)`

```
pry(main)> Faraday.get 'https://dev.testorg.com'
Faraday::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

Openssl version is

```
openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
built on: Mon Apr 20 20:23:01 2020 UTC
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(int) blowfish(ptr) 
compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -Wa,--noexecstack -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/openssl-8Ocme2/openssl-1.1.1d=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAESNI_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DNDEBUG -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1"
Seeding source: os-specific
```

any pointers would help.

A

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me,

```
ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE'
/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem
```

So i had to append the CA cert to cert.pem

```
cat testCA.pem >> /usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem
```

Now

```
    Faraday.get 'https://dev.testorg.com'
=> #<Faraday::Response:0x0000559399a0b1d0
 @env=
  #<struct Faraday::Env
   method=:get,
   request_body=nil,
   url=#<URI::HTTPS https://dev.testorg.com>,
```